# I am learning conditional statements in python.I get syntax error:Invalid statement.(Python 3.6)

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, syntax, syntax-error

This code works when I just use the "if" Statement. When I add "else" it fails.

Here is the code

```
def TotalDistance(Distance_A,Distance_B):
    Distance_X = (float(Distance_A) + float(Distance_B))/1000
    return Distance_X

Distance_A = input("Distance_A:")
Distance_B = input("Distance_B:")
C = str(TotalDistance(Distance_A,Distance_B))

if TotalDistance(Distance_A,Distance_B) > 1 :
    print( C + " KM")
else TotalDistance(Distance_A,Distance_B) < 1 :
    print("Distance too short")

print(TotalDistance(Distance_A,Distance_B))
```

and this is the error I am facing :-

```
File ".\myprogram_1.py", line 11
    else TotalDistance(Distance_A,Distance_B) < 1 :
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `else` doesn't take a condition

Comment: By the way, what about when distance `== 0`

Comment: I'll use a elif statement. @cricket_007

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost had it there just a small tweak makes it work. I have provided a solution followed by the explanation.

```
def TotalDistance(Distance_A,Distance_B):
    Distance_X = (float(Distance_A) + float(Distance_B))/1000
    return Distance_X

Distance_A = input("Distance_A:")
Distance_B = input("Distance_B:")
C = str(TotalDistance(Distance_A,Distance_B))

if TotalDistance(Distance_A,Distance_B) > 1 :
    print( C + " KM")
else:
    print("Distance too short")

print(TotalDistance(Distance_A,Distance_B))
```

Which then we tried as

```
Distance_A:100
Distance_B:200
Distance too short
0.3
```

The problem comes in at the else portion, when using the `else:` it is not necessary to specify the conditional (else: does not take a conditional, you would use else if (`elif`) to do this). Your value specified from `TotalDistance(Distance_A,Distance_B)` can only be greater than one or less than one.

Note that the above code does not take into account when the value `TotalDistance(Distance_A,Distance_B)`  is equal to zero, I did not change this as I am not sure which statement you would like to be executed when this occurs.

Also, check out this link on if-else statements in python to get a better understanding of how they work https://www.guru99.com/if-loop-python-conditional-structures.html .

Comment: You'd be better off linking to the official Python docs. Anyone that says "if loop" doesn't know what they are talking about

Answer (score 0):

I'll use this when the {TotalDistance(Distance_A,Distance_B)} == 0.

Here is the code : -

```
def TotalDistance(Distance_A,Distance_B):
    Distance_X = (float(Distance_A) + float(Distance_B))/1000
    return Distance_X


Distance_A = input("Distance_A:")
Distance_B = input("Distance_B:")
C = str(TotalDistance(Distance_A,Distance_B))


if TotalDistance(Distance_A,Distance_B) > 1 :
    print( C + " KM")
elif TotalDistance(Distance_A,Distance_B) == 0 :
    print("You are going no where")
else :
    print("Distance too short")
```

Comment: Pleasure is mine @Kiran kudpane , glad to hear you managed to get it sorted out :)